# How to use 'easeOutBack' easing with Velocity.js

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

I am using [veloicty.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) to animate elements on my site. I'm able to use just about any other easing method except `easeOutBack`. I thought I read that everything is included within the library except the 'bounce' effects.

I have also included jqueryui into my project just as a last-ditch effort to see if that helped. No luck.

Here is what I am using:

```
$('element').mouseenter(function (event) {
    $(this).find('h2').velocity({
        'top': 20
    }, {
        'duration': 300,
        'easing': 'easeOutBack'
    });
```

Or, is it a case where I need to manually create that effect by using 2 velocity calls. One to take the element's position past 20, then the other back to 20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#easing):

> Pre-packaged into Velocity are jQuery UI's easings, except for the back, bounce, and elastic easing types.

So unfortunately you won't have any luck with the `easeOutBack` easing.

However, since it's a simple predefined cubic bezier you could simply use its values to generate the effect using: `[0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275]` as a value for the `easing` option.

Comment: `except for the back` == `easeOutBack`

Duh. Thank you for the (now) obvious. :)